# Array of arrays? in macro

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a function `Sub fRemoveCharList(ColArray As Variant, char As Variant)` (code below) to remove a list of characters w.r.t a list of header names.

If I call it with...

```
Sub RemoveCharList()

  fRemoveCharList Array("field1","field2","field3"), Array("]", "&", "%")
End Sub
```

...it works fine

But if I instead go...

```
Call fRemoveCharList(("field1","field2","field3"), ("]","&","%"))
```

...which is my preferred way, I get a "Type mismatch" error. Do I need to have an array of arrays to use it like this?

I have Googled how to proceed, but found nothing I could work with.

The function:

```
Sub fRemoveCharList(ColArray As Variant, char As Variant)

Dim x As Variant
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim Heading As Variant
Dim headingFound As Range
Dim lngColIndex As Long

For Each Heading In ColArray
    On Error Resume Next
    Set headingFound = Range("1:1").Find(What:=Heading, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)
    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0: On Error GoTo -1
    If Not headingFound Is Nothing Then lngColIndex = headingFound.Column

  LR = Cells(Rows.Count, lngColIndex).End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 1 To LR
      With Cells(i, lngColIndex)
          x = .Value
          For j = LBound(char) To UBound(char)
              x = Replace(x, char(j), vbNullString)
          Next
          .Value = x
      End With
    Next i
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Run fRemoveCharList Array("field1","field2","field3"), Array("]", "&", "%")` instead of `Call`.

Comment: Or: `Call fRemoveCharList(Array("field1","field2","field3"), Array("]","&","%"))`

Comment: Try adding the correct signature to your method - Sub fRemoveCharList(ColArray() As Variant, char() As Variant) - since you are passing in arrays..

Comment: Sorcei's, thank you for the response. I tried `fRemoveCharList(ColArray() As Variant, char() As Variant)` but it caused a error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either of:

```
Run fRemoveCharList Array("field1","field2","field3"), Array("]", "&", "%")
```

Or:

```
Call fRemoveCharList(Array("field1","field2","field3"), Array("]","&","%"))
```

Comment: David, thanks, I used the 2nd method and it worked fine. Also I tried adding the `Sub fRemoveCharList(ColArray() As Variant, char() As Variant)` as well per `Sorcei's` comment but this caused a error so I remove the `()`.  `Thanks again greatly appreciate the response`